# Issues Displaying glb Model on HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to have a glb model displayed in a simple HTML webpage that I am building. To do so, I am following the API documentation from [Model Viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/). I am unsure why the model is not displaying correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv = "x-ua-compatible" content = "IE=edge">
        <meta name = "viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
        
        <title>portfolio</title>

        <style>
            .box {display:flex;}
            mode-viewer {width: 800px; height: 500px; margin:0, auto}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "box">
            <div>Hey check this out</div>
            <div>
                <model-viewer camera-controls alt="Model" src="assets/Model/Tavern.glb">
                </model-viewer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 

</html>
```

The file is stored in an assets folder and is pathed correctly. This is the outcome

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqZNo.png)
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I've read some posts that mentioned an error when loading a glb file, but I am not receiving these errors.

Answer (score 2):

put the absoulute url include `http://localhost` example :   `http://localhost/glb/assets/Model/Tavern.glb`

make sure your path is correct, cause when i check everything works fine after change the url, please check this snippet :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv = "x-ua-compatible" content = "IE=edge">
        <meta name = "viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
        
        <title>portfolio</title>

        <style>
            .box {display:flex;}
            mode-viewer {width: 800px; height: 500px; margin:0, auto}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "box">
            <div>Hey check this out</div>
            <div style="border:1px solid black">
                <model-viewer camera-controls alt="Model" src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/shishkebab.glb">
                </model-viewer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I am using VScode and copied the path:`http: //localhost/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Git/PersonalWebsite/assets/Model/Tavern.glb`. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: you need to run the index.html to server, are u using PHP ?

Comment: No, how do I use PHP?

Comment: What currently programming language do you used?

Comment: install this tool first https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html for using PHP